# Error with mysql perfect square function

Tags: mysql, function

This is the function I am trying to create in mysql:

```
CREATE FUNCTION isPerfectSquare (testNum INT) 
RETURNS BOOLEAN 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE sqrtint INT; 
    SET sqrtint = sqrt(testNum); 
    DECLARE result BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE; 
    IF sqrtint * sqrtint = testNum THEN 
        SET result = TRUE; 
    END IF; 
    RETURN result; 
END;|
```

I have my delimiter set to |, or I wouldn't have even been able to make it this far.  mysql comes back with an error near:

```
DECLARE result BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
```

Can someone help me see what I'm doing wrong? I've just written a different function that works fine, that operates in a similar way, and I can't see what I've done differently this time that's making it error out.

Comment: Aren't booleans actually stored as 1 or 0 in MySQL?

Comment: yeah, but I don't think that's the issue, because I used BOOLEAN in the other function I just wrote and that one works just fine.

Comment: @vch `TRUE = 1` and `FALSE = 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the declarations have to be at the beginning of the block:

```
CREATE FUNCTION isPerfectSquare (testNum INT) 
RETURNS BOOLEAN 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE sqrtint INT; 
    DECLARE result BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE; 
    SET sqrtint = sqrt(testNum); 
    IF sqrtint * sqrtint = testNum THEN 
        SET result = TRUE; 
    END IF; 
    RETURN result; 
END;|
```

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare.html):

> **DECLARE** is permitted only inside a **BEGIN ... END** compound statement and must be at its start, before any other statements.